# Turning All layers on for all data frames in ArcMap using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, data-frame

I am using ArcMap 10.2. I used the following code to turn all the layers on for the Main Map data Frame.

```
dFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(current_mxd,"Main Map")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(current_mxd, "", dFrame):
        lyr.visible = True
```

Does anyone know how to use ArcPy to turn every layer on for all the data frames?

Comment: for dFrame in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(current_mxd) will cycle through the data frames.. the wildcard is optional.

Comment: All you need is a `for` before dFrame, an `in` where the equals is, empty quotes in the `ListDataFrames`, and to remove the array index.

Answer (score 2):

You use the same coding pattern for looping through your data frames as you do for looping through your layers.

```
for dFrame in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(current_mxd):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(current_mxd, "", dFrame):
        lyr.visible = True
```